# Adding two columns in a dataframe and displaying other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition, multiple-columns

Hello I added two columns and got a column to display the sum of those two columns successfully. However I want to display other columns along with that summed column. For example I would like to show the `ArrDelay` and `DepDelay` or another column if i choose to along with this summed column.

Here is my code below:

```
flight_data_finalcopy["sumDepArr"] = flight_data_finalcopy["DepDelay"] + flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"]
sum_arrival_delay = flight_data_finalcopy["sumDepArr"]
sum_arrival_delay_fliter = sum_arrival_delay[["UniqueCarrier", "AirlineID", "DepDelay", "ArrDelay", "sumDepArr"]]

print(display(sum_arrival_delay_filter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need assign it to new column:

```
flight_data_finalcopy['new'] = flight_data_finalcopy["DepDelay"] + 
                               flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"]
```

Or use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
flight_data_finalcopy['new'] = flight_data_finalcopy["DepDelay"].add(
                               flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"])
```

EDIT by comment:

Remove `sum_arrival_delay = flight_data_finalcopy["sumDepArr"]` and then replace `sum_arrival_delay` to `flight_data_finalcopy`:

Sample:

```
flight_data_finalcopy = pd.DataFrame({'DepDelay':[1,2,3],
                   'ArrDelay':[4,5,6],
                   'UniqueCarrier':[7,8,9],
                   'AirlineID':[1,3,5],
                   'Another_column':[4,8,9]})

print (flight_data_finalcopy)
   AirlineID  Another_column  ArrDelay  DepDelay  UniqueCarrier
0          1               4         4         1              7
1          3               8         5         2              8
2          5               9         6         3              9


flight_data_finalcopy["sumDepArr"] = flight_data_finalcopy["DepDelay"] + flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"]
sum_arrival_delay_filter = flight_data_finalcopy[["UniqueCarrier", "AirlineID", "DepDelay", "ArrDelay", "sumDepArr"]]
print (sum_arrival_delay_filter)   
   UniqueCarrier  AirlineID  DepDelay  ArrDelay  sumDepArr
0              7          1         1         4          5
1              8          3         2         5          7
2              9          5         3         6          9
```

Comment: maybe i was not clear enough earlier on what i wanted. I updated the code above! Please at it again thanks @jezrael

Comment: I  looked over and saw what i missed out , Thanks worked like a charm! @jezrael

Answer (score 3):

You can append the new column to your dataframe:

`flight_data_finalcopy["sumDepArr"] = flight_data_finalcopy["DepDelay"] + flight_data_finalcopy["ArrDelay"]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks ! butsorry maybe i wasnt clear i updated my code  above, I want to try display those columns along with the column "sumDepArr"  @tomasn4a